# GCC optimization: killing variables or memory locations

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to tell the optimizer of recent versions of GCC that a particular variable or memory location is dead at a particular point? Is there a way to tell it that a memory location won't change across a particular call?

For example, such knowledge can help the register allocator and will allow the compiler not to emit unneeded save/restore operations for memory locations (and/or variables).

So, I am looking for something like

```
x = __builtin_undefined ();
```

which overrides `x` with a conceptually undefined value, effectively killing its lifetime.

For the other problem of declaring a location as unmodified, I tried the following sample code

```
void f (int);

int g (int *p)
{
  int t = *p;
  f (t);
  if (t != *p)
    __builtin_unreachable ();
  return *p;
}
```

but at `-O3`, the compiler still accesses the memory twice:

```
g:
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        movl    (%rdi), %edi
        call    f
        movl    (%rbx), %eax
        popq    %rbx
        ret
```

An example for unnecessary stores/loads is given as follows:

```
static void
g (int *p)
{
  /* frobnicates *p */
}

/* Returns the frobnicated value of *p and clobbers *p.  */
int
f (int *p)
{
  g (p);
  return *p;
}
```

The compiler cannot read the comment and so would have to write back the value that `g` calculates to `*p` even when `g` is fully inlined.

Comment: I wonder if you could use UB to convince the compiler something is impossible and then have it optimize from there? Hacky but maybe its the way to go.

Comment: *and will allow the compiler not to emit unneeded save/restore operations for memory locations (and/or variables).* - Like what? Can you give some examples?

Comment: FWIW, clang is not accessing the memory twice for the last snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/cjx8eEzxa

Comment: @EugeneSh. is there any memory model reason that GCC would go back to the pointer? I think there might be post C11/C++11 but this code would be UB if that case was true *anyway* as that would imply a data race?

Comment: I had some success with an inlined function that limits the lifetime of local variables.

Comment: Ok this is weird [replacing the `__builtin_unreachable()`](https://godbolt.org/z/YrYeYvsG6) with an obviously unreachable `return t;` changed the result for GCC.

Comment: Theoretically, marking `p` as `restrict` *should* allow gcc to conclude that it can reuse the previous value of `t` as the current value of `*p`, but it doesn't affect code generation on [godbolt gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/56PzvK3hd). Edit: It does work for [godbolt clang](https://godbolt.org/z/3Kfoooshc).

Comment: @Mgetz I could think of only one use-case. `p` might point to some memory location which is being modified by `f` as a side-effect, and it does not "trust" `__builtin_unreachable` or is unable to deduce the conclusion the OP is expecting.

Comment: @Mgetz I guess it forces gcc to keep the value of `t` alive across the call to `f()` so it can reuse it.

Comment: If `f` satisfies the requirements for GCC `pure` or `const` function attributes, then making this change has the desired effect for GCC at -O3

Comment: @EugeneSh. An added another example at the end of my question.

Comment: @EOF maybe? But it's obviously prunable because that branch can never be taken thus AS-IF takes over. It should be semantically identical.

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis I know; but I would like to have a more fine-grained control. The external function shall be allowed to modify other memory locations.

Comment: @Marc you sure that [last example](https://godbolt.org/z/caKd9P963) is causing issues? Because as soon as optimization is turned on it zips down to something small.

Comment: @Mgetz It still stores the value in the memory; what I am looking for is that compiles `f` basically to return the constant 4 (in your example) after `g` has been inlined.

Comment: @Marc if you're modifying the value pointed to by the pointer that side effect must be reflected in the result. Maybe I'm misinterpreting what 'frobnicates' means in this case but AS-IF requires that any side effects of `g` be visible. If you remove the `*p = 4` then it gets a lot smaller really quickly because the compiler can see `g` has no side effects.

Comment: @Mgetz Exactly; and this is why I am asking about something with the effect of `*p = __builtin_undefined();` effectively clobbering the memory location of `p` and telling the compiler that the side effect of `g` is not observable.

Comment: @Marc that's not allowed by the standard because it would violate AS-IF. The only way to tell the compiler that the memory isn't reused is to use memory that isn't reused. Thus is to copy the value to a [new location that isn't used or available after the call.](https://godbolt.org/z/M3zPdvxEv)

Comment: @Mgetz: It is allowed by the standard because `*p = _builtin_undefined();` would have behavior defined by the C implementation and not by the C standard. While I do not see this being used directly for the purpose of making otherwise legitimate modifications to `*p` not be honored, I see a use in something like `int x = 13; foo(&x); x = __builtin_undefined(); int y = -27; bar(&y);`. In this, the compiler cannot deduce that `x` and `y` may use the same memory, since `foo` could secrete `&x` and `bar` could use it. Telling the compiler `x` is never used again means it can reuse its memory.

Comment: Note that `x = __builtin_undefined();` is not a good approach, though. It merely tells the compiler it may assume the value of `x` will not be used after this assignment (equivalently that any behavior may occur if it is used). However, something could still do `x = 9;`, giving it a defined value again. You would want some construction that specifically tells the compiler the object lifetime is ended, not just the value lifetime is ended.

Comment: Of course, this can be done by exiting the block `x` is defined in. So it is only a concern when we want to delete some object but not objects defined within nested blocks that we are not ready to exit. E.g., in `{ { int x = 13; foo(&x); } int y; bar (&y); }`, the compiler may use the same memory for `x` and `y`. But in `{ int x = 13; { int z = 3*x; foo(&x); int y; bar(&y); bar(&z); } }`, we have no way to tell the compiler `x` and `y` may use the same memory, since we want to hold `z` while `y` is in use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil nitpicker's point: That's an extension, it does not exist within *ISO standard C* but otherwise I get your point. I still think it's easier to just make the intent clear rather than rely on extensions.

Comment: @EOF Could it be that GCC and Clang interpret the `restrict` qualifier differently? Please see this example: https://godbolt.org/z/ebzo3sx3d.

Comment: @Marc there's no ambiguity or implementation defined behavior here with the `restrict` qualifier, `gcc` just fails to optimize it as much as it would be allowed to.

Comment: @EOF Thanks; I filed a bug report for GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104574.